# How to remove an event listener from the dom in vue when another event is triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, devextreme

I am using Devextreme and Vue.js, and I ran into a rather interesting problem. (Perhaps it is due to lack of understanding of Vue's reactivity system.) I have a method that attaches event handlers to a DOM element that is within a devextreme component at runtime like so (Not the best solution, but it is all I could think of at the time.)

```
onFocusIn:(e)=>{
                     let element = e.element.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
                     let selectedElement = element.id.substring(element.id.lastIndexOf("_")+1, element.id.length);
                     //..............
                    ///.......
                    element.addEventListener("click",this.moveCursorToFarLeftStupidBug);
                    element.addEventListener("mouseover",this.moveCursorToFarLeftStupidBug);
                },
```

NOTE: this onFocusIn event pertains to a dx text box dx form simple item, if that matters.

What I would like to do is remove the event handlers on the following event below and not have to wait until the component is destroyed to do so if possible.

This is the event that I wish to utilize to remove the event handlers:

```
onFocusOut:(e)=>{
                    let element = e.element.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
                    element.removeEventListener("click",this.moveCursorToFarLeftStupidBug);
                    element.removeEventListener("mouseover",this.moveCursorToFarLeftStupidBug);
                }
```

However, when I tried to do this, the event handlers would not get purged and I was still able to capture events for mousing over and clicking on the element in question.

I read that the "best place" to remove attached event handlers in Vue is within the beforeUnmount() lifecycle hook, however, I would like to remove these before the component is destroyed. I even tried using this.$nextTick and this.$forceUpdate to update the DOM, but to no avail. Any answer or corrections that need to be made are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: if `this.moveCursorToFarLeftStupidBug !== this.moveCursorToFarLeft` ... then it's not removing the event handler, since you can only remove a handler that was added

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistake. The event handlers were the same name when I initially wrote this for the app.